Does cooking method affect affect acidity of tomato based meal?
I personally like acidic tasting food, particularly tomatoes however I’m wondering if the acidity of the food changes depending on cooking method?
Say you make a sauce or a soup with tomatoes.  I know you can add ingredients such as vinegar, lemon etc to increase the acidity of the soup.  You can also not add things like potatoes or high ph vegetables so as not to increase the ph(lower the acidity of the meal).
I would imagine a tomato product is more acidic based on how concentrated the product is therefore tomato puree(paste in US) would be most acidic followed by pasata(us puree) which is then followed by whole tomatoes. Therefore the more tomatoes you add and concentrated the more it will be acidic.
However I’m wondering about if you make a simple soup eg add 5 tomatoes or a jar of puree(uk pasata), or some us paste(uk purée) to a litre of water.  Does the water decrease the acidity or does it simply dilute the taste but not change the acidity? Therefore if you want a very acidic taste whole tomatoes, paste, pasata etc is better without water based cooking methods?  Would frying the same amount of tomatoes, paste etc in a few tablespoons of olive oil lead to a more acidic sauce than a water based method?
Again I’m not asking about adding alternative ingredients or products which may have had preservatives added.  Just asking about how dry or wet heat methods may affect the acidity of a tomato based meal?
Also in the examples I gave I said adding 5 tomatoes to a litre of water or a jar of pasata to a litre of water.  However what if you used tomato juice instead of water to begin with, would that be far more acidic than tomatoes or pasata in water, I read most of the acid is in the skin and seeds of the tomato but tomato juice is stripped of both.
Thanks

I'm not a chemist, but based on my long ago chemistry courses, the pH (acid or base) of a chemical in solution is based off the concentration of the Hydrogen ion (H+. Properly this is the hydronium ion; H3O+ in solution, but H+ will do).
This is determined by the following equation:
pH = -log10[H+]
or pH = negative log10 of the concentration (denoted by the square brackets "[]") of the hydrogen ion.
However it isn't quite that simple because the chemistry is also complicated by something called a dissociation constant, which is  basically how strongly the chemical holds onto its hydrogen ion. For most of the strong acids (hydrochloric, nitric, sulphuric etc), this constant is so low that it makes no difference to the above equation, but in most organic (in the chemistry sense) acids, like citric acid, malic acid, tartaric and acetic acids, it does. This equation is the following:
pH = pKa + log10([A-]/[HA]) where pKa is the dissociation constant of the acid/base in solution and [A-] and [HA] are the concentration of the acid and its conjugate base in solution.
Citric acid is the predominant acid in tomatoes, with malic and ascorbic acid (vitamin C) also being present. I have no idea how to do the calculations for multiple acids in solution, so I'll keep this simple with only citric acid, which is actually more complex than you might think - it has 3 different dissociation constants because it has 3 acid groups per molecule, these are the groups with an O with two lines before a O-H group. These constants are 3.13, 4.76 and 6.4:

Image source: PubChem. https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/citric_acid#section=Structures
I'm going to assume that in solution all 3 acid groups are used, so the pKa will be 3.13 because this will give the most liberated hydrogen ions and hence the lowest pH (more acid).
According to Agius et al, 20181, the content of citric acid in tomatoes is about 2000 milligrams per litre or 2 grams/l (0.243 oz/gallon) if you puree them.
In chemistry number of moles = mass/molar mass, (n = m/Mr) and concentration =  n/volume (c = n/v). Citric acid has a molar mass of 192.12 grams per mol.
So:
conc citric acid in tomatoes = (2.0 g/192.12 g/mol)/1.0 litres
c = 0.0104 mol per litre or 10.4 millimol/litre.
If you plug this back into the pKa equation above, this concentration of citric acid, in water alone, should give you a pH of 2.613. You can check this calculation on a calculator like this one. This won't quite be the situation in tomatoes, as there will be some basic components (neutralizes acid) in there. Of course, as you remove volume by say dehydrating or concentrating you will concentrate the acids too, so a tomato paste will be more acidic than a juiced tomato liquid. You could use the above information and equations to work it out for various volumes.
Now, you have 5 tomatoes - according to this webpage, the average weight of a tomato is between 75 and 150 g per medium size tomato and you are adding this to a litre of water, however, this website reckons that there are about 1 large "medium" tomato (at the upper end of the medium scale, or 150 g) per 200 ml volume, so 5 tomatoes could make about 1 l. Adding to water or stock will only dilute any acid that is present in the tomatoes, so you will not have as concentrated acid as you might otherwise. If you added these same tomatoes to a tomato juice, you are essentially adding tomatoes within tomato volume, so you should have more concentrated tomato and higher acidity.
Reference:

Agius C, von Tucher S, Poppenberger B, Rozhon W. Quantification of sugars and organic acids in tomato fruits. MethodsX. 2018 May 25;5:537-550. doi: 10.1016/j.mex.2018.05.014. PMID: 30023316; PMCID: PMC6046607.

